# Migrate Schema.org questions to webmasters.se?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

The tag [schema.org](/questions/tagged/schema.org), being about a way of marking up HTML documents so search engines can add rich data to their results, seems like it's a better fit over at webmasters.se. Should the schema.org questions be migrated over there?

Comment: Do you mean migrating all the existing questions with that tag?

Comment: yes I do. I'm sorry I didn't clear that up.

Comment: Migrating *all* of them? I don't think so, too much of a hassle especially for older questions.

Comment: Some of these questions may actually be related to programming. Definitely shouldn't batch migrate them all.

Comment: Not all of them, mayby, but questions like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889199/how-to-use-schema-org-to-markup-a-forum might be more ontopic at webmasters.se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the 20 questions tagged [schema.org](/questions/tagged/schema.org) there are only 5 unanswered, yet only 5 questions score 1 or more vote. So if your reasoning for migration is to get greater attention, then yes flag for migration (on a case by case basis).

On the other hand WebMasters does not have a schema.org tag but for whichever questions do contain "schema.org" (16 questions) there are a *relatively* high number of votes and views.

What you risk by asking for a migration is the OP of the questions and answers losing ownership until they associate their accounts on WebMasters

The better approach would be to migrate a good quality question that was *recently* posted. Migrating in bulk just puts monotonous overhead for moderators on both sides and in addition floods the WebMasters home page.